# Issue while adding controls dynamically

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I was adding and removing controls dynamically. However, I have a small requirement.

Below one is Jsbin code. 
https://jsbin.com/tuxacitoju/1/edit?html,output

1. Open the link.
2. Click “Adperson”
3. Now click Remove two times.

Observe, all control are removed and then you are not allowed to add controls.

My page should have at least one set of controls.

Thanks,
Balu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add and if statement to check if there are more than one rows before deleting. For example:

```
$("#associationRemove").on("click", function(){
  if ($(".cloneMe").length > 1) $(".cloneMe:last").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
  $("#associationRemove").on("click", function(){
      if($(".cloneMe").length > 1){
        $(".cloneMe:last").remove();  
      }
  });
```